# prime vue pass through attributes not working with tailwind

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css, primevue

I am using the primevue library to implement a file upload, it works that it uploads the file for me, but I am using tailwind because I want to manually style it myself but the problem is that some of the pass through attributes work but some don't.

this is the code that I have:

```
 <FileUpload
                    accept="image/*"
                    :show-upload-button="false"
                    choose-label="Select Files"
                    cancel-label="Clear all"
                    :max-file-size="10000000"
                    @select="onSelect"
                    :multiple="true"
                    :file-limit="3"
                    :pt="{
                        buttonbar:
                            ' bg-gray-50 border border-b-0 border-gray-400 border-solid gap-2 p-2 rounded-t-md',
                        root: 'flex flex-col mb-2',
                        chooseButton:
                            ' cursor-pointer bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md p-2',

                        cancelButton: 'bg-red-500 text-white rounded-md p-2',
                    }"
                >
                    <template #empty>
                        <p>Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>
                    </template>
                </FileUpload>
```

the buttonbar, root and chooseButton classes get applied but the cancelButton classes get ignored so my code will look very messy,
can anyone help me?

Comment: "classes get applie" - do they? :pt is supposed to pass the attributes, not classes. It should likely be `:pt="{ buttonbar: { class: ' bg-gray-50 ...` in order to work

Comment: According to the documentation: "If the value is a string or a function that returns a string, it is considered as a class definition and added to the class attribute of the element."